# ui-router removes front slash when user uses 'go to forward' button

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router (v0.2.11) with html5 mode

Have the following states:

```
  stateHelperProvider.setNestedState({
      name: 'stages',
      'abstract': true,
      url: '/:bakery/:city',
      templateUrl: '/app/stages/stages.html',
      controller: 'stagesCtrl',
      children: stageStates
  });


  var stageStates = [{
      name: 'chooseCake',
      url: '/velg-kake',
      templateUrl: '/app/stages/choose-cake/choose-cake.html'
  };

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/oops');
```

Bakery and City are optional parameters.

For example I'm on home page:

```
mysite.com/home
```

If I go to link something like this:

```
mysite.com/bakery//velg-kake
```

go back (to home) and go forward it's ok, 
but when I use

```
mysite.com//city/velg-kake
```

go back (to home) and go forward I get

```
mysite.com/oops.
```

I have tried to see the $location path in 'otherwise' function handler and I have gotten

```
/city/velg-kake
```

instead of

```
//city/velg-kake
```

So seems ui-roter removes first slash.

Comment: Are you using 0.2.11?  I believe this is a bug that will be fixed in 0.2.12.

Comment: @ChrisT will try when it will be released. Currently I wrote some temp logic for fixing this in otherwise rule handler.